# How do I get the value of $a$ in the formula $v =u+at$?

Tags: vectors, physics, mathematical-physics

I've been set a physics assignment where I need to make a 2D projectile physics engine. Here's one of the tasks:

> A trajectory  in  $2D$  for a   projectile  that    has a   launch  **velocity  of  20  ms-1**  and a   **launch
>
>   angle of  $45^o$** . **Time   step    =   0.01**  seconds. The    gravity vector
>   is    $(0.0, -9.81)$. Show    the position    vectors and velocity    vectors
>   on    a   console for demonstration    purposes

I know where all the values are coming from, and I know their values, but I don't understand where I get the value of $a$ in the $v=u+at$ (this is the formula I must use)

My question is, *how do I work out the value of $a$*, so that I can perform the equation?

Comment: $a$ is given as the *gravity vector*.

Comment: Well, $a$ seems to be acceleration and if the projectile is lunched at constant speed, the only acceleration comes from gravity, i.e. $a = (0,-9.81)$. But, I might be wrong, you should clarify what variables are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\vec{a}=(0,-9.81)$. The horizontal acceleration is zero which is given and the only acceleration on the projectile is the acceleration due to gravity which is also given. You will have a horizontal and vertical (sometimes $x,y$ or sometimes $i,j$) velocity and acceleration.